# Shared preferences retuning as null

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am tryting to simply check to load the correct starting activity i do:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

   public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  MyApplication.getAppContext().getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean onBoardingComplete = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true);

        if(onBoardingComplete){
            Intent navIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationStartActivity.class);
            startActivity(navIntent);
        }else{
            Intent onBoardIntent = new Intent(this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
            startActivity(onBoardIntent);
        }


    }
```

I get a null pointer exception on the initialisation of sharedPreferences effectively line 5 here. My sharedPrefs file exists in the storage data/data/com.myap/shared_prefs/sharedPrefs.xml

I have no idea why this would return null.

Answer (score 2):

move it inside onCreate because outside context is null

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();


        boolean onBoardingComplete = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true);

        if (onBoardingComplete) {
            Intent navIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationStartActivity.class);
            startActivity(navIntent);
        } else {
            Intent onBoardIntent = new Intent(this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
            startActivity(onBoardIntent);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: And move `sharedPreferences.edit()` to the else branch, if it only only sets `"firstRun"` to true.

Comment: For only retrieving values from the ```SharedPreferences``` you don't need the Editor.